# dynamodb low with net core 3.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Some dynamodb readings are very slow, I even have readings that take 27min, but in my load tests I do not have those high peaks in my tests, the maximum time is 500ms, these high times occur in the production environment.

I do not understand what is the reason for this delay
Will it be netcore3.1?

i am using asynchronous too

I am using NET CORE 3.1

i am use on-demand

I have 13,848 records in my dynamo table

In the cloudwatch metrics I don't see any spike that represents 27 minutes, I am very concerned about this

Comment: What is your model you are using provisioned or on-demand? it might be possible you hit the maximum capacity which you can in dynamo DB events

Comment: i am use  on-demand

Comment: I have 13,848 records in my dynamo table

Comment: In the cloudwatch metrics I don't see any spike that represents 27 minutes, I am very concerned about this

Comment: Where is your server hosted?

Comment: Docker container, ecs

Comment: Memory= 256 and cpu = 128, I have 8 instance the my container

Comment: how is your test environment is different than your production environment?

Comment: I am using an endpoint to connect to dynamodb, I do not go to the Internet to communicate with dynamodb

Comment: Resources, we have instances with little capacity in a test environment and in production we have very good resources